# Query with large WHERE clause causes timeout exception in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

```
clients = (IQueryable<client>)opts.ApplyTo(_dbContext.sp_client.FromSqlRaw(
                           SqlQuerys.GetVisibleClients(),
                                                    new NpgsqlParameter("providerId", providerId),
                                                    new NpgsqlParameter("userId", userId))
                           .Where(predicate)
                           .Include(q => q.NameDataQualityValue)
                           .Include(q => q.SsnDataQualityValue)
                           .Include(q => q.VeteranStatus)
                           .Include(q => q.Answers).ThenInclude(q => q.AnswerValue)
                           .Include(q => q.Answers).ThenInclude(q => q.Question)
                           .Include(q => q.HouseHoldsRelationship).AsQueryable());
            }

List<client> visibleClientsList = client.ToList();
```

In `client.ToList()`, the code throws a timeout error - the issue in predicate it have the condition a switch statement

```
 "gt" => predicate.And(q => q.Answers.Any(q =>
                                    (_dbContext.da_answer.FromSqlRaw(
                                        SqlQuerys.GetTopVisibleAnswers(),
                                         new NpgsqlParameter("providerId", providerId),
                                         new NpgsqlParameter("userId", userId),
                                         new NpgsqlParameter("effectiveTimeSpan", dateEffective.Value)).Any(o => o.answer_id == q.answer_id) &&
                                    q.Question.virt_field_name == answerCondition.virtualFieldName && q.val_date != null &&
                                    q.val_date.Value.Date > dateValue.Date))),
```

Comment: if you remove the `Where(predicate)` it works? the amount of `Include` is scary. i suspect you hit maximum memory or something. if you can check on database log for any error or warning, that would be better.

Comment: `Include` doesn't matter all that much - it controls eager loading, not memory consumption. Databases handle terrabytes of data with just GBs of memory too. Delays are caused by inefficient queries though, not LINQ expressions and this code is *very* hard to read, much less understand. It almost certainly results in multiple nested queries with all those `Any`s. It's also impossible to guess what the raw SQL queries do.

Comment: In any case, LINQ isn't meant as a SQL replacement. It's a query language for an ORM. ORMs load graphs of objects, they don't run reports. What you have here is almost certainly a report query. It would be a *lot* simpler and infinitely easier to optimize to create a VIEW with the query you want and map your classes to it rather than try to emulate the view's SQL as a LINQ query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure exactly what difference it would make if you express the JOINs in a SQL view, or in a SQL query that's translated from a .NET LINQ query; if at the end of the day you use the same ORM to map the same result shape to the same .NET classes, things should be very similar.

Comment: @ShayRojansky for starters, you don't need any kind of JOIN with ORMs. It's the ORM's job to generate the JOINs from the relations between entities. If you use JOINs it means there are no relations between entities. That's a bug. At the end of the day, your LINQ query will be far more complex and brittle than the SQL query you tried to avoid, and usually slower because of unexpected problems that prevent the use of indexes

Comment: @marc_s the way to diagnose this is to inspect the SQL produced by EF Core, and use PostgreSQL EXPLAIN to see the plan produced from it ([see the EF perf docs for some pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/performance-diagnosis)). That would help understand if e.g. an index is missing for your WHERE clause.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the user above is using Include, which is usually a way to express JOIN in an SQL query - this is just how EF Core works. What do you see as a bug here?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it seems you're generally advocating to avoid LINQ (and therefore .NET ORMs). Regardless of what I think about this advice, it doesn't seem relevant to this specific question in any way.

Comment: @ShayRojansky no, that's not what I said at all. What is the query though? You have absolutely no idea. It's hidden behind `FromSqlRaw` and `GetTopVisibleAnswers()`. Quite likely that's a function call that gets executed for every row of the query table's. Even if you capture the raw SQL query you won't be able to fix this

Comment: @ShayRojansky as for `generally advocating to avoid LINQ (and therefore .NET ORMs).` no. I'm advocating against blindly using tools without understanding what they're for, or when they are the *wrong* tool for the job. If anything, I prefer using ORMs instead of the low-level single entity "repositories" that are behind a lot of SO problems. And I have no problem mixing both EF Core and Dapper code in my projects, each doing its own job. Or using *multiple* DbContexts, some for CRUD, others for reporting

Comment: @BagusTesa  if you remove the   Where(predicate) then its working .

in GetTopVisibleAnswers()  
 public static string GetTopVisibleAnswers()
        {
            return ($"SELECT vca.* FROM top_visible_client_answers(providerId, userId, effectiveTimeSpan) vca");
        }

Comment: @user19024826, uhh, `SqlQuerys.GetVisibleClients()` is this part homebrew? i just realized your linq seems to mix and match multiple stuff.. also, are you using `linqkit` for composing the `predicate`?